# crond not sending mail to non-root user

Tags: cron

RHEL8 system here. Outputs from /etc/cron.daily... produce the expected email output, but my user's own crontab doesn't. Here's a test that sums up my problem:

```
~$ crontab -l
MAILTO=dh
 *  *     * * * echo "HERE"
~$ sudo tail /var/log/cron
[sudo] password for dh:
Nov  6 08:33:42 deham01lx013 crond[2177]: (dh) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/dh)
Nov  6 08:34:01 deham01lx013 CROND[3503836]: (dh) CMDOUT (HERE)
Nov  6 08:34:13 deham01lx013 crontab[3503855]: (dh) LIST (dh)
```

FWIW, the mails from the root cron jobs are correctly mailed to "dh" via an alias in /etc/aliases. Also when I do `~$ echo "HELLO" | mail dh`, I get the mail. The cron daemon isn't running with any weird options, either:

```
~$ ps afx | grep cron
   2177 ?        Ss     0:12 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

Any hints?

Comment: Does removing `MAILTO=dh` make things better? The default is to mail any output to the owner of the schedule, so you should not need to specify an explicit `MAILTO` address. I'm wondering if doing so is confusing something.

Comment: Does `MAILTO=root` work better? I guess you have a local sendmail (or any other MTA/MDA), what do its logs say?

Comment: MAILTO=root or no mailto at all don't make a difference. Neither does using stderr `echo "HERE" 1>&2` instead of sdout. The cron log shows correct execution of the command, see original post.

Comment: This crontab entry: ` *  *     * * * echo "HERE"  | mail dh` diligently sends me a mail every minute. So I could just hang a "mail pipe" to all my crontab entries, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

By refining my searches more and more I did manage to find the answer here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1114164/cron-not-sending-output-to-email-but-writing-output-var-log-cron

In short, crond had been running since before I installed mailx so it just wasn't aware that there was a mail service available. Fixed.